# Image on UIButton is invisible on the device

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

*NOTE I do not have this problem while running my app through the simulator.

I have an image on a UIButton which works fine.  However upon selecting another button... the image of the first button is supposed to change.  It works in the ios 4 simulator just fine.  However when I load it Via Ad Hoc onto my iPhone, when the image is supposed to change, it just turns blank.

Here is my code for the image change...

`UIImage *upDinoUp = [UIImage imageNamed:@"upDinoUp.png"];`

`[Dino setImage:upDinoUp forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Do you have a Retina display on the device?  Potentially your Retina-sized image is corrupt, but on the simulator, you're using the 1x version.

Comment: I have an iPod Touch 2G and this sounds spot on... how would I format my image size within the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simulator differs from the device in that its handling of image names is case insensitive. So, maybe your string @"upDinoUp.png" has the wrong case for one of the characters.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the image format may not be supported by the device. Please check it

Comment: The image format is .png and my icon is .png so is the initial image found on the button before I try to change it. It is supported however. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html